# Packing, caching, JS and CSS in PHP that differentiate between development and production environment

Tags: php, javascript, css, optimization, deployment

I am trying to make **development easy** and have **highly optimized** output in production.

The goals of what I am trying to do is:

- **Make production pages fast!** I would like that the **Google Page Speed** and **YSlow** return the **best** scores. This means:

  1. **Combine and compress** JS files and CSS and **position the group** in the right place (bottom or top of the page) in the HTML. For .js Google Closure seems the best choice.
  2. **.JS and .CSS are smartly cached** but be sure that they get reloaded when of the .JS or CSS componet is updated. 301 File not changed etc.
  3. **Cache type**: I think cache on disk is fine. Consider APC and Memcache or Redis if they significantly improve speed.
  4. Capable to specify and use **lazy load** of .JS when necessary or at least not to block the page rendering.
  5. (Optional) Compress the HTML too.
- **Make website development easy**:

  1. Use short command in the .php file when you want to include .js or .css and compress them only in the production environment

     - Use syntax like **pack_js(['first.js', 'second.js' 'third.js'])** and **pack_css(['first.less', 'second.less' 'third.css'], true)**
     - It is easy to configure develpment or production environment. Maybe just a call to **SetDebug(true or false)**. **Default production**
     - Easy to set up **cache folders** and **source folders**
  2. **Use of LESS** to make CSS development sucks less. Automatically compile LESS files in CSS in production but use of **LESS.js** in development so that each time you change the .less file in development it is updated on the server.
  3. (optional) In development it includes a JS and a LESS console similar to the shell at https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/webdevel.html

**Note:** it is OK to use Apachee modules and .htaccess files if they significantly speed up the process. But it should be able to set them up quicky, ideally with just a setup command.

Is there something that do this? Or what are the best resources to start?

I would prefer a solution that consists of a PHP script (eventually few .php files, .htaccess and compressing executables) that compresses the .JS with the Google Closure Compiler and compress/compile the CSS/LESS files stripping out useless comments and white spaces. A special cookie could be used on production server to output the development version.

I would like to have:

A php function usable like this: **pack_js(['first.js', 'second.js', 'third.js'])** that write something like:

On developments servers:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/first.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/second.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/third.js"></script>
```

On production servers (if the special cookie is not present):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cache/12a42323bfe339ea9w.js"></script>
```

Another function: **pack_css(['first.less', 'second.less', 'third.css'], true)** that write something like:

On developments servers:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/static/css/first.less" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/static/css/second.less" type="text/css" />
<link href="/static/css/third.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.0.21.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    less.env = "development";
    less.watch();
</script>
```

On production servers (if the special cookie is not present):

```
<link href="/cache/46537a8b8e876f7a8e7.css" type="text/css" />
```

the second parameter specify if the less.js should be output on the development server

Obviously 12a42323bfe339ea9w.js and 46537a8b8e876f7a8e7.css are the optimized, packed and  compiled version of the script. This solution should be able to detect when a source file change and recompile the scripts for production. It should be configurable to regarding locations of the script and type of caching (disk is fine). Ideally the pack_js should probably have an option to make possible lazy load of the js in production.

Every suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Some components I found around:
<code>http://fadeyev.net/2010/06/19/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/ The "offcial" less in JS.</code> -----

   http://leafo.net/lessphp/  Less implementation in PHP but it looks buggy -----

   http://github.com/sunny/csscaffold  Something similar to LESS but not exactly -----

   http://cjohansen.no/en/ruby/juicer_a_css_and_javascript_packaging_tool  (a JS/CSS packer but in Ruby) -----

   http://code.google.com/p/php-closure/ (but I could have the java version on the server)

Comment: If you link the un-compiled CSS/LESS files, then the page will not render properly. I think the best you can do is link to the compiled but not-yet-minified version. I personally just use separate development/production servers for this sort of thing (I don't like working directly on live sites), but you could also add/remove `.min` from the CSS/JS filenames based on the presence of a cookie. I don't see what advantage a temporary filename like "46537a8b8e876f7a8e7.css" conveys, though I do see that quite a bit on larger sites.

Comment: No, with less.js, it compiles the .less file in the browser. It is great for development. It also reload the .less file when you save it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you could do that. +1

Comment: @Chris, what are your updates?

Comment: I created a version that is working and running but I need to clean it up to before release to public =)

Answer (score 6):

Still working on exploring the best solution leveraging the resource already available.

**CSS-JS-Booster** and **Turbine** so far looks like the best starting point: http://github.com/Schepp/CSS-JS-Booster and http://turbinecss.org/

### Other JS/CSS Combiners solutions and articles

- http://code.google.com/p/minify is good but seem a little to hard to configure.
- http://rakaz.nl/code/combine Let you use sintax like this: http://www.creatype.nl/javascript/prototype.js,builder.js,effects.js,dragdrop.js,slider.js (not exactly the best) I also think I saw a patch to this script but I cannot find it now.
  (example of usage http://brainfart.com.ua/post/code-cache-combine/)
- http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/72 and http://www.ejeliot.com/samples/combine/combine.phps  Ed Eliot combine.php solution. It only let you have specify once the file to merge
- http://aciddrop.com/php-speedy/ other solution.
- http://www.artzstudio.com/2008/08/using-modconcat-to-speed-up-render-start/ Use of mod_concat and overview of other solutions
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/ That is a WordPress Plugin. It is very interesting but probably to much work to make it independendt from Wordpress.
- http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/combine-your-js-css-files-for-faster-loading CakePHP solution

### Resource for JS compression and caching:

- http://code.google.com/p/php-closure/ PHP script that let you combine .js files ancd combile thought the Google Closure REST API. Check timestamps and cache the combined version locally.
- http://dean.edwards.name/download   JS packer compressor/obfuscator. I am not sure how long the decompression take. But it was able to shrink the jQuery 1.4.2 compiled/minified with Closure to 50639 bytes from 71946 (almost 30% reduction!) with Base62 Encode on! It would be interesting to compare the gzipped versions. Regarding JS obfuscation Packer optimizer make a little more difficult to tamper in your JS code.
- http://thinkvitamin.com/dev/serving-javascript-fast/ Great discussion about gzip and caching
- http://cjohansen.no/en/ruby/juicer_a_css_and_javascript_packaging_tool Ruby Juicer JS/CSS packaging tool

### LESS compilers/tutorials/tools:

- http://designshack.co.uk/articles/css/using-less-js-to-simplify-your-css3 Less.js tutorial/introduction.
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-you-need-to-check-out-less-js Presentation of less.js (useful comments)
- http://fadeyev.net/2010/06/19/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/ and http://github.com/cloudhead/less.js It is a LESS compiler written in JS and can also be added in the browser. Great for development
- http://lesscss.org/ What LESS is. Originally written in Ruby but there are implementation in a lot of different fanguages,
- http://leafo.net/lessphp/ Less compiler written in PHP (it does not seem updated)
- 960 is another way to make it things easier; http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/03/fight-div-itis-and-class-itis-with-the-960-grid-system/
- http://github.com/everzet/sfLESSPlugin LESS in symphony
- http://drupal.org/project/less  Drupal CSS Preprocessor
- http://github.com/sunny/csscaffold A PHP parser of something similar to LESS but not quite
- http://code.google.com/p/maven-less-plugin/ maven-less-plugin uses rhino, envjs and less.js  to translate the less-code to css during the process-source phase of your maven build. In the end you get a artifact with ready-to-use css code.

### At Deployment time options:

- http://phing.info/docs/guide/stable/ Phing is build/deployment system in PHP
- http://www.capify.org/index.php/Capistrano The Ruby solution

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a project build system to deploy your application to the production server that does just that? For PHP you might like [Phing](http://phing.info/), since it would allow you to write extra plugins in PHP, that you can execute while deploying. Other options you might want to consider of you take this route are [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/index.php/Capistrano) (and there's lots of others), but these require knowledge of other languages (granted, you could start the php parser from them if you really wanted to...).

Comment: That may be a possible route. I did not know Phing. I will look into that. Do you have something to suggest that already do what I ask? Maybe some example files?
I would like to keep a easy syntax into the .php so I can control the order and position of groups of .js and .css are in the output HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Great Question!

I've worked with a process with similar requirements, but we took somewhat of a different approach. I realise its maybe not exactly what you're after, but would still make some recommendations:

1. Make the compression/compilation part of the shipping process.(You may already be doing this, but it wasn't clear from the above).
2. Compress/compile it on the development servers too. It might be a hassle for debugging/testing but you want to be able ensure the production version and test versions are as similar as possible. If you have the luxury of multiple development stages, then you could possibly compress on one of them.
3. Only do the compression/compilation if it passes some sort of quality scan (e.g. [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/))
4. Don't combine the modules - keep them separate. The performance benefits you will gain will be so negligible, as to be almost pointless.
5. Don't change the HTML, just change the dependant modules content.

I realise its a bit different from what you were intending, but in my experience it leads to a more robust development promotion model.

Comment: I meant to have the compilation part on fly the 1st time a .js change and then cache the file generated. (1) It may be Ok but it must be automatic at deployment time. (2) I agree. Test should run on prod. ver. of the files. (3) Yes, creating a nice way to signal error in the JS is something that I would like to have. (4+5) Not true. Each module is a http request to the server. To make the site fast you need to reduce them to the min plus less.js must be only in production. HTML can be also stripped out of useless comments and white spaces. Do you have any suggestions on where I should start?

Comment: There's nothing I know that already does this for you. It sounds like you have quite a specific process to your organsiation, and you'll need to build it yourself. I don't know the scale of your modules, or the expected traffic, but would still contest 4 and 5 with you. I guess we'll ahve to agree to disagee ;)

Comment: Re 4-5: There are a few articles online that describe the benefits of combining js and css files (ex: http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2007/04/10/faster-page-loads-bundle-your-css-and-javascript/ ). I suggest to read High Performance Web Sites -> http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529307/ and Even Faster Web Sites -> http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596522315 and