# Loading multiple CSS/JS files at the same time using a server side script

Tags: javascript, css

I've noticed a few sites doing this recently and I'm pretty sure I've come across it before. But can anyone give me a link through to somewhere that describes loading multiple files at the same time.

I often see something like the following:

```
<script src="/load/script/common:jquery-1.4.4.min/common:jquery-ui-1.8.9.fx.min/common:jquery.scrollTo-min"></script>
```

Presumably it's processed server-side and is a lot more efficient way of loading multiple scripts - Is that right?

Thanks guys.

EDIT - Is anyone able to advise on whether it's possible to do it server side?

Comment: Interested in how to enable in on server-side. Could you edit your question towards that?

Comment: A much more complete question/set of answers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501295/packing-caching-js-and-css-in-php-that-differentiate-between-development-and-p - Unfortunately some of the links are out of date though.

Comment: Benchmarks - http://www.sitepoint.com/faster-page-loads-bundle-your-css-and-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume it's a normal request, `/load/script`.

The files to load would be parsed out of the request and streamed as a single response.

Comment: Good point. So literally all it's doing is echo'ing out the contents of each of the files passed to it. Never even crossed my mind that it was that straight forward. Quite like to see some benchmarks of this kind of process or something like head.js - I'll have to do some research. Thanks.

Comment: @christian.thomas I don't know that I'm *right*, mind you, I'm just not sure what else it could be--a request for a JS file is just another request. It could also minify/compress/cache/etc. as well, and since it's a single URL, could be cached by the browser as well.